# Can't align three text widget in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

I'd like to create three text areas in a tkinter window and make them dinamically resizable. I thought that one solution was to pass the width and height parameters in pixels (such as height=int(win_height/2)), but as I read it isn't possible, in fact the width and height parameters in a tk.Text widget are calculated by characters for each line and column. I've also tried to pass the width and height parameters in percentages (such as height=50%) but it returns me a syntax error.

I've been trying to find out a solution for this problem in the net, and the best code I've found is this:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")

# Text Box
first_textbox = tk.Text(root, width=25, height=10, bg='yellow')
second_textbox = tk.Text(root, width=25, height=10, bg='blue')
third_textbox = tk.Text(root, width=50, height=20, bg='red')

# Packing
first_textbox.grid(column=1, row=1)  
second_textbox.grid(column=1, row=2)
third_textbox.grid(column=2, row=1, rowspan=2)

root.mainloop()
```

By running this code I obtain a window with three different text areas which aren't dinamically resizabled and which take more space than the actual window width. I hope you can help me. 
Sorry for any English mistake, it is my second lenguage

Comment: Can you please explain what output you are expecting from this code above because it will just make 3 text boxes that arent dynamic? You may be better using the pack() function instead of grid(). Also refer to creating a frame inside your root that can be dynamically changed which would contain your text box at full frame size as a work around

Answer (score 0):

`grid` has several documented parameters to help you do what you want. You simply need to use them.

By default, `grid` won't give widgets any extra space -- they take up only the space they need and no more. If you widgets to be allocated extra space, you have to explicitly arrange for that.

For example, if you want all widgets to grow and shrink equally, you need to configure the rows and columns to have an equal `weight` greater than zero. That will tell grid how to allocate any extra space when the window is bigger than the size requested by all of the widgets.

For example:

```
root.grid_rowconfigure((1,2), weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure((1,2), weight=1)
```

That just tells `grid` what to do with *extra* space. If instead, you want two or more rows or columns to have exactly the same size, you can use the `uniform` option to tell `grid` that you want the rows or columns to have a uniform (identical) size.

For example, if you want both columns 1 and 2 to have the same width, you can give each column the same value for the `uniform` option. Note: the value passed to `uniform` can be anything you want. The important thing is that they are configured to have the same value.

```
root.grid_columnconfigure((1, 2), uniform="equal")
```

That alone won't solve the problem. You also must tell `grid` that you want the widgets to fill the space given to them. You do that with the `sticky` parameter, which tells grid to "stick" the widget to one or more sides of the allocated space.

To get the widgets to fill all allocated space you can give the string `"nsew"` which stands for "north, south, east, and west" which represent the four sides of the given space.

```
first_textbox = tk.Text(root, width=25, height=10, bg='yellow')
second_textbox = tk.Text(root, width=25, height=10, bg='blue')
third_textbox = tk.Text(root, width=50, height=20, bg='red')
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. I will try your advice and in case it won't work I'll post another question here. Thank you